# Normalising parts in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of lists of coordinates that I'm using to make a density plot. A simplified version of this list would be something like

```
list={{{0,1},{1,2},{2,3},{3,4}},{{3,2},{2,3},{1,4},{0,5}},{{3,1},{2,2},{2,4},{3,5}}}
```

I want to normalise the y coordinates wrt the list they're in. I can do this for each list individually using

```
Part[Flatten[Part[list, 1]], 2 ;; All ;; 2]/Tr[Transpose[Part[list, 1]][[2]]] & /@ Part[list, 1][[2]]
```

but this is a bit of a mess and in my actual code I have 150 lists. Is there a way of doing this for multiple lists at the same time?

Comment: Can you show what is the expected result in this case?

Comment: Is `list[[All, All, 2]] = Normalize /@ list[[All, All, 2]];` what you want?

Comment: Yes I think that works! Thanks!

Comment: Is `list[[All, All, 2]] /= Total[list[[All, All, 2]], {2}]; list` wrong?

Comment: I think either should work, just one keeps the coordinates together and one extracts the y coordinate?

Comment: @JJH both modify original `list`, I just didn't include `list` at the end to show it. The main difference is the normalization, Coolwater uses `Normalize[{1, 1}, Total]` as your example and I use `Normalize[{1, 1}]` which is what I understand by normalization..